# с++: range-based циклы - ситуации для мастхэв использования

Tags: c++, c++11

Подскажите, является ли использование range-based циклы обоснованными в любой ситуации, где у меня есть только

```
for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
```

Т.е. это не съедает производительность и не расходует лишнюю память.
И есть есть только перебор всех элементов контейнера, то лучше использовать

```
for (auto &it: data)
```

?

И еще вопрос: если я использую некоторые методы итераторов - то тут использовать rabge-based цикла не получится?

Т.е. если было

```
for (x::iterator it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); it++)
{
    count += it.my_func();
}
```

на

```
for (auto &it: obj)
{
    count += it.my_func(); // какое-нибудь другое обращение
}
```

изменить не получится, поскольку доступа к самому итератору нет, хотя он и использовался где-то внутри?

Comment: В принципе да, лучше в такой ситуации использовать range-based for, так как это сокращает код. Полная развёртка заголовка цикла не даёт никакой дополнительной информации. Но с другой стороны "маст хэв" это не стоит называть, каждый делает, как ему удобнее, в некоторых проектах, например, локальный стайлгайд не разрешает использовать такие конструкции. В общем использовать стоит, если только нет каких-то особых предпочтений.

Comment: Range-base раскрывается в обычный цикл. Так что существенной разницы нет.

Comment: А такой вопрос - если я использую некоторые методы итераторов - то тут уже такого не выйдет? Т.е. `for (x::iterator it = obj.begin(); it != obj.end(); it++){count += it.my_func();}`  - тут уже трюк с range-based не пройдет?

Comment: Почему не пройдёт, в заголовке for (auto &it: data) it это в точности итератор, вы можете использовать его методы, сколько угодно.

Comment: @zcorvid `it` в этом случае как раз не итератор, а ссылка на элементы `data`

Comment: @VTT , не знал, значит выше глупость написал.

Comment: Как показал пример в комментариях, лучше использовать традиционные циклы с индексами (меньше будет ошибок в понимании  кода **другими людьми**)